# Confusion on why an object wont draw a circle when trying to grab the window size

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

So, I have a pane being made in one class

```
@Override //Overridden nerd
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    //makes a ball
    Ball ball = new Ball();

    //pause and resume animation
    ball.setOnMousePressed(e -> ball.pause());
    ball.setOnMouseReleased(e -> ball.play());

    //increase/decrease speed
    ball.setOnKeyPressed(e-> {
    if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) {
        ball.increaseSpeed();
    }
    else if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {
        ball.decreaseSpeed();
        }
    });

    //creating a scene and setting its background
    Scene scene = new Scene(ball, 500, 500);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Random Walker");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    ball.requestFocus();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }   
}
```

and im trying to get the animation to start the ball at the center off the pane, and then bounce off the walls (im not on the bouncing part yet so I know that isnt perfect yet but im trying)

My problem is that when I try to get the ball to draw off of the current size of the window its not drawing anything at all, but will work if I manually put in the default screen size. any insight would be great, as I've been struggling with trying to finding any way to do this for a while, thanks.

```
public class setup extends Application {

    @Override //Overridden nerd
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    //makes a ball
    Ball ball = new Ball();

    //pause and resume animation
    ball.setOnMousePressed(e -> ball.pause());
    ball.setOnMouseReleased(e -> ball.play());

    //increase/decrease speed
    ball.setOnKeyPressed(e-> {
    if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) {
        ball.increaseSpeed();
    }
    else if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {
        ball.decreaseSpeed();
        }
    });

    //creating a scene and setting its background
    Scene scene = new Scene(ball, 500, 500);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Random Walker");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    ball.requestFocus();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.
And unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: The example of the code is straight from a java text book example, I was just attempting to make the window resizable. I’ll see if I can get a good example of the issue when I get home, thanks.